# How to combine result of two test in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javacsript function, her result 2 arrays, one contains the 10 top turnover of customers and the other contains the 10 bottom turnover of customers.

I did my Graph and I fill it by the two arrays.

I want add a `scatter` type `triangle` with a green color above each chart that contains a positive turnover and bellow each chart that contains a negative turnover and red color.

[I found this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/sozhojst/).

```
var query1 = {{repair_semestre1}};
var query2 = {{repair_semestre2}};
function formatName(o) {
  return "Client: " + o.client + ", LRU.: " + o.article + ", semester t/o: " + o.turnovers + " " + o.percent;
}
var data = {};
var output = [];
var max = [];
var min = [];
var client;
var article;

[query1, query2].forEach(function (query, semester) {
    query.Client.forEach(function (clientId, index) {
                                               var client = data[clientId] = data[clientId] || {};
        var clientArt = client[query.LRU[index]] = client[query.LRU[index]] || [0, 0];
        clientArt[semester] = query.round[index];
    });
});

for (client in data) {
    for (article in data[client]) {
        var turnovers = data[client][article];
        if (turnovers[0]!=0) {
            output.push({ client, article, turnovers, 
                                                                                                                       percent: turnovers[0] === 0 ? turnovers[1] :
                                                                                                                      ((turnovers[1] - turnovers[0]) / turnovers[0]) *100 });
 }
    }
}

output.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.percent - a.percent;
}); 

var target = output.slice(0,10);   
var clients = [];
var lrus = [];
var percents = [];

for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
            clients.push(target[i].client);
            lrus.push(target[i].article);
            percents.push(target[i].percent);   
             
}
var target2 = output.slice(-10);
var clients2 = [];
var lrus2 = [];
var percents2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < target2.length; i++) {
            clients2.push(target2[i].client);
            lrus2.push(target2[i].article);
            percents2.push(target2[i].percent); 
             
}    
target={client: clients, lru: lrus, percent: percents};
target2={client: clients2, lru: lrus2, percent: percents2};
return  {
    target:target,
    target2:target2
}
```

I should do another function to test the value of each turnover. I did this function shown below, but always it return just the result of the first test.

```
var target1={{calcul_turnover.target.percent}}
var target2 ={{calcul_turnover.target2.percent}}

for(var i =0; i < target1.length; i++){
if(target1[i] < 0){
    
return 0
}else
return 1
    }
for(var i =0; i < target2.length; i++){
if(target2[i] < 0){
    
return 0
}else
return 1
    }
```

How can I combine the results of the two tests?
Thank you

Comment: Pro-tip: format + indent your code more nicely. You'll sooner get answers with readable code, especially if it this much code.

Comment: ok ! I noted... and I'm not waiting the answer from you @PeterB